# Need to show text into like html code in Web-view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have text in firebase which contains link i need to shows like hyperlink in webview in flutter. Both images attached below
[image: Firebase Image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this package ? for basic HTML : [flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.8.5+3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html_core) for more advance use this one : [flutter_html: ^2.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)

I have user flutter HTML in more then 3 projects and if you want load any URL or webview then user FLUTTER-webview or In-APP-WEBVIEW it will load full website in flutter mobile app like amazon.

Comment: Thanks for answer i have text and this text contains urls and emojis all things and check second image which i upload. When url exist in text i need to shows highlighted and clickable.

Comment: you can just use HTML clickable property after using the flutter HTML package. it will also you to use all HTML functionality so you can easily able to click, hover, and many more.

Comment: Okay let me check